# Execution order of try, catch and finally block

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch-finally, finally, try-finally

Suppose I have some C# code like this:

```
try {
    Method1();
}
catch(...) {
    Method2();
}
finally {
    Method3();
}
Method4();
return;
```

My question is, provided no exception is thrown, will Method3() be executed before Method4(), or is it that the `finally` block is only executed before a `return`, `continue` or `break` statement?

Comment: This seems like it would be trivial to test.

Comment: May I know why you didn't write a simple console application to see what will happen and in what order?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a beginner developer and I didn't come up with the idea of trying it myself. After a search on Google I couldn't find an answer so I decided to ask it here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the `finally` block of the [`try-catch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw.aspx) will be executed in order as you would expect, and then execution will proceed onto the rest of the code (after completing the entire `try-catch-finally` block).

You can think of the entire [`try-catch-finally`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dszsf989.aspx) block as a single component that would function just like any other method call would (with code being executed before and after it).

```
// Execute some code here

// try-catch-finally (the try and finally blocks will always be executed
// and the catch will only execute if an exception occurs in the try)

// Continue executing some code here (assuming no previous return statements)
```

**Example**

```
try 
{
    Console.WriteLine("1");
    throw new Exception();
}
catch(Exception) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("2");
}
finally 
{
    Console.WriteLine("3");
}
Console.WriteLine("4");
return;
```

You can [see an example of this in action here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Bx57gx) that yields the following output :

```
1
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 4):

The sequence will always be

```
try 
--> catch(if any exception occurs) 
--> finally (in any case) 
--> rest of the code (unless the code returns or if there is any uncaught exceptions from any of the earlier statements)
```

Useful resource: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwc8s4fz.aspx

Comment: rest of code is also skipped for uncaught exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, provided no exception is thrown, will Method3() be executed before Method4(),

Yes, `Method3` will be executed before `Method4` because whether an exception is thrown or not, the execution will go to the finally block and then proceed from there.

> or is it that the finally block is only executed before a return, continue or break statement?

No, it is always executed after the try block, whether there was an exception or not.

**Important Point**

If you have this:

```
try 
{
    DoOne();
    DoTwo();
    DoThree();
}
catch{ // code}
finally{ // code}
```

If an exception is thrown by `DoOne()` then `DoTwo()` and `DoThree()` will never be called. Therefore, do NOT think that the entire `try` block will always be executed. Actually, only the part until the exception is thrown will be executed and then execution goes to the `catch` block.

Finally will be executed always-despite whether there was an exception.